# jquery forms file upload: why do field values reset?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-forms-plugin

I have a form with some elements like:

```
<input type="text" name="maxResultsPlain"
                    id="maxResultsPlain" class="number" value="10">
```

The form includes one input of type 'file'. The whole business is wired up to a REST server via `$(form).ajaxSubmit(submitOptions)`, invoked from the submitHandler of the validate plugin, http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/.

Whenever I submit, the form input fields go back to their default values as per the `value` attribute. Is there a way to prevent this?

A Chrome DOM breakpoint suggests that this is happening as a result of the machinations of the validation plugin, so I suspect that the issue is there.

Central spot in the code:

```
$("#query-upload").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $(form).ajaxSubmit(submitOptions);
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you check data returned form server, because as you said you are using REST standard, there is possibility that form contents is being loaded from server!...
If you want form fields to be empty use $(form).ajaxSubmit({clearForm:true, resetForm:false}); If no one of these helps, then check that you have latest version of jquery-form or set form fields manually using jQuery, also try to set break point over ajaxSubmit itself to see what's going on using firebug...

Comment: I am sure that this is not the case. I wrote every line of this.

Comment: I'm afraid but i've seen jquery-form source, it will skip form-test and clear if those options are false, and there is no other reference to those function in jquery-form but the ajaxSubmit function, could you please set break point there, and check it out!...

Comment: Yes, but the backtrace in the debugger points to validate, not forms.

Comment: I'm sorry, is the form posted using ajax, because of the file upload in form may cause application to work unexpectedly...

Comment: validate function, are you using another plugin but jquery and jquery form, because, i can't see validate function in jquery form, i'm sorry...

Comment: As I wrote when I edited, I'm using the validate plugin. Stand by for more edit.

Comment: actually i answered this question long before i add comment thought you are using jQuery validator, and i'd check that one out too, i currently have jquery-validate 1.8.1, and there is no code that could change fields values. i'd deleted that answer thought i'm wrong..

Comment: I suspect that some of the class-changing in there provokes the browser. I have coded the obvious workaround.

Comment: I'd simulated all the information you gave me into a simple project, but there was no problem,i think we need more information.

Answer (score 0):

There are [resetForm](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#options-object) and clearForm options that you can try and set to false to see if that will help.

Comment: And setting them explicitly to false didn't help any.